# Array mapping in PHP with keys

Tags: php, arrays, dictionary

Just for curiosity (I know it can be a single line `foreach` statement), is there some PHP array function (or a combination of many) that given an array like:

```
Array (
    [0] => stdClass Object (
        [id] => 12
        [name] => Lorem
        [email] => lorem@example.org
    )
    [1] => stdClass Object (
        [id] => 34
        [name] => Ipsum
        [email] => ipsum@example.org
    )
)
```

And, given `'id'` and `'name'`, produces something like:

```
Array (
    [12] => Lorem
    [34] => Ipsum
)
```

I use this pattern a lot, and I noticed that `array_map` is quite useless in this scenario cause you can't specify keys for returned array.

Comment: Probably not, but you can write your own function :)

Comment: array_map can take a custom function, and you can use that to specify the array keys.

Comment: @Ariel How? I can't find a way to specify keys for `array_map`  **returned** array.

Comment: @lorenzo-s In the callback, output the array with the keys you need.

Comment: @Ariel Ok, but `$out = array_map(function($o) { return array($o->id => $o->v); }, $objects);` returns and array of arrays... Maybe there's a function that has to wrap this "first" result?

Comment: have you come wiht a solution for this?

Comment: This does the trick:

return array_reduce($options, function(&$r, $x){ $r[$x->property] = $x->property2; return $r;});

Comment: You  can use array_column($arr, 'name', 'id'); you can also see in my answer for more details

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Just use [`array_reduce`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php):

```
$obj1 = new stdClass;
$obj1 -> id = 12;
$obj1 -> name = 'Lorem';
$obj1 -> email = 'lorem@example.org';

$obj2 = new stdClass;
$obj2 -> id = 34;
$obj2 -> name = 'Ipsum';
$obj2 -> email = 'ipsum@example.org';

$reduced = array_reduce(
    // input array
    array($obj1, $obj2),
    // fold function
    function(&$result, $item){ 
        // at each step, push name into $item->id position
        $result[$item->id] = $item->name;
        return $result;
    },
    // initial fold container [optional]
    array()
);
```

It's a one-liner out of comments ^^

Answer (score 5):

I found I can do:

```
array_combine(array_map(function($o) { return $o->id; }, $objs), array_map(function($o) { return $o->name; }, $objs));
```

But it's ugly and requires two whole cycles on the same array.

Comment: You should probably do this manually (i.e. a `foreach` loop) - it'll likely be faster than this.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is to use an array_column()

```
$result_arr = array_column($arr, 'name', 'id');
print_r($result_arr );
```

Out Put

```
Array (
    [12] => Lorem
    [34] => Ipsum
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use a LINQ port like [YaLinqo](https://github.com/Athari/YaLinqo) library*. It allows performing SQL-like queries on arrays and objects. Its [`toDictionary`](http://athari.github.io/YaLinqo/docs/classes/YaLinqo.Enumerable.html#method_toDictionary) function accepts two callbacks: one returning key of the result array, and one returning value. For example:

```
$userNamesByIds = from($users)->toDictionary(
    function ($u) { return $u->id; },
    function ($u) { return $u->name; }
);
```

Or you can use a shorter syntax using strings, which is equivalent to the above version:

```
$userNamesByIds = from($users)->toDictionary('$v->id', '$v->name');
```

If the second argument is omitted, objects themselves will be used as values in the result array.

<sub>* developed by me</sub>

Answer (score -1):

Because your array is array of object then you can call (its like a variable of class) try to call with this:

```
 foreach ($arrays as $object) {
    Echo $object->id;
    Echo "<br>";
    Echo $object->name;
    Echo "<br>";
    Echo $object->email;
    Echo "<br>";
 }
```

Then you can do

```
 // your array of object example $arrays;
 $result = array();
 foreach ($arrays as $array) {
       $result[$array->id] = $array->name;
 }

   echo "<pre>";
   print_r($result);
   echo "</pre>";
```

Sorry I'm answering on handphone. Can't edit the code