# Implode a mult-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, implode

I'm trying to implode a multi-dimensional array, but I'm missing something.

This is the array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Brand 1
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Brand 2
        )
)
```

So after some google-ing I found a couple of solutions but they all gave me different errors.

I read that `array_map()` should work, but I can't figure out what the second parameter should be.

I'm getting the following error:

> Warning: array_map() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in

This is my code:

```
$imploded = implode("','",array_map($brand_array));
```

`$brand_array` is a newly created array constructed from an `in_array` function

The goal is to get a comma seperated string like:

```
brand1, brand2
```

Comment: you can get reference form http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12050892/array-mapping-in-php-with-keys

Comment: I think that what you are describing would be to implode the array after you flatten it (as it is called in underscore for example). If you google something like "php array flatten" you will find several solutions like http://davidwalsh.name/flatten-nested-arrays-php or https://gist.github.com/kohnmd/11197713

Comment: Yeah but I need an comma seperated list like: `brand1, brand2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it seems like you're a bit confused how to use [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php). But this should work for you:

```
echo implode(",", array_map(function($v){
    return implode(",", $v);
}, $arr));
```

So as an example:

```
$arr = [
        [1,2],
        [1,2],
    ];
```

With `array_map()` you go through each innerArray and [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) it by a comma, so you end up with following array:

```
Array ( [0] => 1,2 [1] => 1,2 )
```

Now you have a one dimensional array and you have to implode the return value of `array_map()` again and you implode it again by a comma and you will end up with:

```
1,2,1,2
```

Comment: This answer is aimed at the OP with better explanation. +1. I was 9 seconds earlier, so I have that going for me which is nice.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed explanation. Very clear now and I understand why I couldn't directly use `implode()`. +1

Answer (score 2):

[`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) expects you to add a callback function as first parameter and the array as second parameter.

You can also see this if you look at the signature of the function:

> array array_map ( **callable $callback , array $array1** [, array $... ] )

**Parameters:**

- Callback:

  - Callback function to run for each element in each array.
- Array:

  - An array to run through the callback function.

You have only the array in `array_map` You need something like this:

```
array_map('functionname', $array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
$input = array(
  array(
    'brand 1'
  ),
  array(
    'brand 2'
  )
);


echo implode(', ', array_map(function ($entry) {
  return $entry[0];
}, $input));
```